# How to set Index paramter "analyzer" value to "English.Microsoft"

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

{
      "resourceType": "index",
      "resources": [
        {
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "abc",
          "fields": [

```
        {
          "name": "Source",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": true,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": <here i want to give English-Microsoft>,
          "synonymMaps": [

          ]
        },
```

Please give me the correct value name. When I have "english.microsoft", it gave bad request error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the analyzer to *"en.microsoft"*

Below is a link to our documentation about adding language analyzers. It includes a language analyzer list.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-language-analyzers